# Excel Upload in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am uploading excel in asp.net. but one column not read .

```
 protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection myconn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
        string paramExcelSheetName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.Equals(Server.MapPath("~/UploadExcel/" + paramExcelSheetName));

        string strFileType = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName).ToLower();
        string path = string.Concat(Server.MapPath("~/UploadExcel/" + FileUpload1.FileName));
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.Delete(path);
        }
        if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xls")
        {
            excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
        }
        else if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xlsx")
        {
            excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Persist Security Info=False;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
        }
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(path);
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
        query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] ";
        conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
        OleDbDataReader oledbdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


        #region readline by line
        if (oledbdr.HasRows)
        {
            while (oledbdr.Read())
            {
                if (!oledbdr.IsDBNull(0))
                {
                    if (!oledbdr.IsDBNull(0))
                    {

                        sr =Convert.ToInt32( oledbdr["SrNo"].ToString());

                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                    if (!oledbdr.IsDBNull(0))
                    {

                        certificate = oledbdr["CertificateNo"].ToString();

                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                    if (!oledbdr.IsDBNull(0))
                    {

                        cr = oledbdr["CR"].ToString();

                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                    //if (!oledbdr.IsDBNull(0))
                    //{

                    //    cr = oledbdr["Pass"].ToString();

                    //}
                    //else
                    //{

                    //}
                    #region

                    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO test1 (SrNo,CertificateNo,CR) VALUES('" + sr + "','" +certificate+ "','" + cr + "')", myconn);

                    try
                    {
                        myconn.Open();
                        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        myconn.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        myconn.Close();
                    }
                    #endregion
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion

        conn.Close();

    }

}
```

one column certificate not read certificate value like 737737373737/En2

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
query = "SELECT SrNo,CertificateNo,CR FROM [Sheet1$] ";


     FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/uploadmedicine/") + FileUpload1.FileName);
                if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null)
                {
                    string path = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
                    string connectString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("~/uploadmedicine/") + FileUpload1.FileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;\"";
                    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectString);
                    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT SrNo,CertificateNo,CR from [Sheet1$]", conn);
               }
```

Comment: "Sir problem in oledb connection string not in query

Comment: in Database column value like this 990120613/EN2
990130286/EN1
990140254/EN1
990140255/EN1
9.9014e+008
9.9014e+008
9.9014e+008